# Stripe checkout.js - passing custom params to token callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

I'm following this example integration from Stripe Docs (slightly modified in order to be able to add click handlers to more than one button:

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
<button id="customButton">Purchase</button>
<script>
  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_jPVRpCB1MLjWu2P71eTvXBZD',
    image: '/square-image.png',
    token: function(token) {
      // Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
      // You can access the token ID with `token.id`
    }
  });

  $('.pay-deposit').click( function(e) {
    // Open Checkout with further options
    handler.open({
      name: 'Demo Site',
      description: '2 widgets ($20.00)',
      amount: 2000
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

In my particular case I have a few buttons like:

```
<button class='pay-deposit' booking-id='3455'>Pay Deposit</button>
<button class='pay-deposit' booking-id='335'>Pay Deposit</button>
<button class='pay-deposit' booking-id='34'>Pay Deposit</button>
```

... and obviously I'd like to pass a booking-id of clicked button somehow to token callback. Couldn't find any example or explanation covering this seemingly simple case... any help much appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a little bit late, but maybe it will help someone else.  This is modified from a Rails example:

```
# HTML file
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
<button class='pay-deposit' data-booking-id='3455'>Pay Deposit</button>
<button class='pay-deposit' data-booking-id='335'>Pay Deposit</button>
<button class='pay-deposit' data-booking-id='34'>Pay Deposit</button>

# JS file
$('.pay-deposit').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Get booking information from database
  var booking_id = $(this).data('booking-id');
  $.getJSON("/bookings/"+booking_id, function(data) {

    // Open Checkout with further options
    handler = stripe_checkout(booking_id);
    handler.open({
      name: "My Bookings",
      description: data["description"],
      amount: data["amount"],
      email: data["email"],
    });

    // Close Checkout on page navigation
    $(window).on('popstate', function() {
      handler.close();
    });
  });
});

function stripe_checkout(booking_id) {
  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_jPVRpCB1MLjWu2P71eTvXBZD',
    token: function(token) {
      // Send the charge through
      $.post("/charges/create", 
       { token: token.id, booking_id: booking_id }, function(data) {
        if (data["status"] == "ok") {
          window.location = "/some-url";
        } else {
          // Deal with error
          alert(data["message"]);
        }
      });
    }
  });
  return handler;
 }

# Bookings controller
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    attrs = @booking.attributes
    attrs.merge!("email" => current_user.email)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: attrs.to_json }
    end
  end
end

# Charges controller
class ChargesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    booking = Booking.find(params[:booking_id])
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(card: params[:token])

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      customer:    customer.id,
      amount:      booking.amount,
      description: booking.description,
      currency:    'usd'
     )

    if charge.paid
      # Do some things for successful charge
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: {status: "ok"}.to_json }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: {status: "fail", message: "Error with processing payment.  Please contact support."}.to_json }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I won't have a chance to test it now but it points me into right direction

Comment: This works (sort of) but is unnecessarily complicated. It also results in a multi-second delay between the time your customer clicks and when the Stripe checkout dialog comes up because you are calling StripeCheckout.configure in the wrong place. See my answer for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2):

Move your token initializer from configure to open.

```
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_jPVRpCB1MLjWu2P71eTvXBZD',
    image: '/square-image.png'
  });

  $('.pay-deposit').click( function(e) {
    var data = $(this).data('booking-id');
    // Open Checkout with further options
    handler.open({
      name: 'Demo Site',
      description: '2 widgets ($20.00)',
      amount: 2000,
      token: function(token) {
          // here you go!
          alert(data);
      }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

And switch to:

```
<button class='pay-deposit' data-booking-id='3455'>Pay Deposit</button>
<button class='pay-deposit' data-booking-id='335'>Pay Deposit</button>
<button class='pay-deposit' data-booking-id='34'>Pay Deposit</button>
```